# How to draw multiple Lewis structures from the same molecular formula?

Tags: molecular-modeling, structure, cheminformatics

I am learning about Lewis octet theory and the following formulae were shown as **guidelines** to draw Lewis structures:

$$
\begin{align}
V &= \text{total valence electrons}\\
R &= \text{required number of electrons for complete octets}\\
B &= \text{bonding electrons} = R-V\\
N &= \text{non-bonding electrons} = V-B = 2V-R\\
\text{number of bonds} &= \dfrac{B}{2}
\end{align}
$$

#### Example of Lewis Structures of $\ce{C4H4}$

For the structure $\ce{C4H8}$:

$$
\begin{align}
V &= 4\times 4 + 8\times 1 = 24 \\
R &= 4\times 8 + 8\times 2 = 48 \\
B &= V-R = 24 \\
\text{number of bonds} &= \dfrac{B}{2}=12 \\
\end{align}
$$

Now, we do know the isomers of $\ce{C4H4}$, which all follow the above stated rules.

| Molecular Formulae | Structures | Remarks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $\ce{C4H8}$ | [image: isomers of cyclobutane C4H8] | Ring-chain isomerism; Positional Isomerism; Diastereoisomerism |

This also tells us that the **guidelines** help us enumerate the isomers of a compound.

#### Some More Examples

| Molecular Formulae | Structures | Remarks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $\ce{CO3^{2-}}$ | [image: resonance structures of carboxylate anion] | Resonance structures |
| $\ce{HSO3-}$ | [image: tautomers of hydrogensulfite] | [Inspired](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/174440/125117)* |
| $\ce{C6H6}$ | [image: different bonding in benzene] | The benzene dilemma |
| $\ce{C3O2H6}$ | [image: tautuomers of hydroxypropanal] | Tautomerization |

*requires special consideration for the expanded octet of $\ce{S}$

I know not all examples cover all isomers, but just to give an idea of the various applications of the **guidelines**.

#### Question

I was wondering if there are some works or perhaps algorithmic approaches to enumerate all structures that comply with the rules, with perhaps modifications to include hypo- and hyper-octet compounds, and just how much information is contained in a molecular formula.

Comment: If you only need those structures that have been experimentally synthesized, then I believe the easiest way is to search in any chemical compound database that support the use of chemical formula as a keyword. Otherwise I think the problem is hard, as there are structures with valid Lewis structures but do not exist due to e.g. extreme steric demands.

Comment: I assume you are searching for constitutional and stereoisomers. This question discusses  it in more detail:
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10620/is-there-a-mathematical-generalization-for-the-number-of-isomers-structural-and

This software/PhD thesis looks promising: https://github.com/csms-ethz/CombiFF